# Eclipse blanking out uppercase "F" for final static vars or enum values

Tags: java, eclipse

Getting back into Java and Eclipse is throwing me for a loop.  When I declare a static or enum, if uppercase "F" is used in it, Eclipse blanking it out and it looks like a space.

```
    public final static int OFFICE_1;
    public enum OFFICELIST {OFFICE_1, OFFICE_2 (2) }
```

When I put in code like this Eclipse blanks out the uppercase "F" letters in the editor.  The Fs are still there.  I.e. I can copy and paste into something else and they show up.

```
    public final static int O  ICE_1;
    public enum OFFICELIST {O  ICE_1, O  ICE_2 (2) }
```

I can't figure it out for the life of me.  If I remove "final" or "static" from the first one, the Fs show up.

Eclipse: 2020-12 (4.18.0) Build 20201210-1552
OS: CentOS 7

Comment: Try changing font ...?

Comment: Actually that did fix the problem.  It was using Monospace Regular and when I changed fonts the Fs became visible.  That is strange.

Comment: I notice that this happened only for `FF` (you didn't show single `F`), and it smells like a bug in the font or font engine relating to ligatures on bold-italic `FF`.

Comment: Please show a screenshot of what you are talking about.